# Query on Google Maps API

Tags: google-maps, maps

I am new to Google maps API. Lets take two locations A and B on the map. I know that maps API would provide me the routes between the two points. (if available). Lets take another location C. I like to know if its possible to find out the nearest location D (to C), which lies in between A and  B. With the maps API, would it be possible to find the above information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is certainly possible. What you describe is anlogous to the "drag to modify route" functionality of maps.google.com The mouse would be your "C" and the draggable marker that appears on the route would be your "D".
Working demo here:

http://www.marsrutai.info/directions.htm